# Is it possible to make pattern matching lazy in Idris?

Tags: idris

In Haskell we can do the following without getting a runtime error ([ref](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html)):

```haskell
mytake  0     _           =  []
mytake  _     []          =  []
mytake  n     (x:xs)      =  x : mytake (n-1) xs

print( mytake 0 (undefined::[Int]) )
```

In Idris, we can do a similar definition, but the behavior is different:

```idris
mytake : Integer -> List a -> List a
mytake  0     _           =  []
mytake  _     []          =  []
mytake  n     (x::xs)      =  x :: mytake (n-1) xs

printLn( mytake {a = Nat} 0 ?undefined )
```

In this case we get `ABORT: Attempt to evaluate hole Main.undefined`. I know Idris is not a lazy language, but my impression was that pattern matching parameters might be separate from the logic for evaluation of data structures (which can be sidestepped in Idris, e.g. with `Stream`).

In addition to understanding if there is a way around this, I'd also appreciate knowing why Idris behaves in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I understand right , this could work

```
module Main

mytake : Integer -> Lazy (List a) -> List a
mytake  0     _          = []
mytake  _     []         = []
mytake  n     (x::xs)    = x :: mytake (n-1) xs


main : IO ()
main = printLn (mytake {a = Nat} 0 ?undefined)
```

But it gives me strange error while compiling

```
andrey@linux:~/idris> idris -o test test.idr
idris: src/Idris/Core/CaseTree.hs:(645,1)-(654,51): Non-exhaustive patterns in function varRule
```

Answering to the second part of your question: 
This is mostly because of eager evaluation is more predictable. This quesion is in an unofficial FAQ

https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/wiki/Unofficial-FAQ#why-isnt-idris-lazy